# Pyodbc update cursor

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc, pytz

Hi, I have a script on Python with SQL and I use fecthall() method to extract the elements I want and all great until there, because I want do modify two columns (datetime.date and datetime.time) to another timezone but I read docs and Its seems its not veare easy...

For now I have the next piece of code fetching the table and then trying to covert firts the date to another timezone, I know... Its a date but if in Spain now is 12am from 5/12/2017 in Mexico is 5pm from 04/12/2017 soooo...

BTW Im using **pytz**

```
cursor.execute(cadenaSQL + cadenaSQL_dos)
            su_dict[base+' hagent'] = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in su_dict[base+' hagent']:
                row = list(row)[0]
                print row
                row[0] = hUTC.localize(datetime.datetime.combine(row[0], hoyUTC.time()).astimezone(hMexico))
```

For now I got this error with that code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "cms_V2_30m.py", line 1535,
>   in 
>       main()   File "cms_V2_30m.py", line 1444, in main
>       select_hagent()   File "cms_V2_30m.py", line 211, in select_hagent
>       row[0] = hUTC.localize(datetime.datetime.combine(row[0], hoyUTC.time()).astimezone(hMexico)) TypeError: 'datetime.date' object
>   is unsubscriptable

EDIT:

I think I´m close, the problem now is with row object, because it is a tuple... so it is inmutble, so I am trying to find a way to change this vale...

The New code:

```
    for row in su_dict[base + ' hagent']:
        print row[0]
        #list(row)
        #print my_date[0]
        #print datetime.datetime.combine(my_date[0], hoyUTC.time())
        row[0] = hUTC.localize(datetime.datetime.combine(row[0], hoyUTC.time())).astimezone(hMexico)
```

The new error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "cms_V2_30m.py", line 1538,
>   in 
>       main()   File "cms_V2_30m.py", line 1447, in main
>       select_hagent()   File "cms_V2_30m.py", line 214, in select_hagent
>       row[0] = hUTC.localize(datetime.datetime.combine(row[0], hoyUTC.time())).astimezone(hMexico) TypeError: 'tuple' object does not
>   support item assignment

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to chain the .astimezone() to the wrong entity. Maybe try `row[0] = (hUTC.localize(datetime.datetime.combine(row[0], hoyUTC.time())).astimezone(hMexico))`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is with overwriting `row` within the loop. Try this instead?

```
for row in su_dict[base + ' hagent']:
    my_date = list(row)[0]
    print my_date
    row[0] = hUTC.localize(datetime.datetime.combine(my_date, hoyUTC.time()).astimezone(hMexico))
```

Comment: nope, Now I got this error: `ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime`

Comment: If your date is timezone naive, then you'll have to use `timedelta` instead.